# Python can't find module even the packages have __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
├── aoo
│   └── aoo1
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── a.py
├── boo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── boo1
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── b.py
│   ├── boo2
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── base
│   │   │   └── boo2_1.py
│   │   ├── main.py
│   └── time.py
└── database
    ├── __init__.py
    └── handler.py
```

I am using python 3.9.2

inside of `boo/boo1/b.py` I have `BModule` defined
I would expect in `boo/boo2/main.py` I can do

```
from boo.boo1.b import BModule
```

However python is telling my boo module can't be found, even tho there is a **init**.py file inside `boo` and `boo1` folder

and when I print out sys.path from main.py

```
['/Users/okoo/Code/projectRoot/boo/boo2', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

I don't see any of the directories in the path. what is going on?

Ideally I like to setup my project so that every python files import is relative to the project root.
for example if I want to use `a.py` from `handler.py` inside of `database`. I would do

```
from aoo.aoo1.a import StuffDefinedInADoTPY
```

Comment: Please post the value of `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Putting your `main.py` inside your folder tree is a mistake, in my opinion.  Python doesn't know where the "top of your tree" is.  If you put it at the top level, it should work.  In lieu of that, you can put `sys.path.append( os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/../..'))` at the beginning of `main.py`.

Comment: echo $PYTHONPATH returns nothing.

Comment: if you mean my `sys.path` I updated the question

Comment: I think a lot of these issues come down to the question of whether you are writing a program or a library. __init__.py is very library focused. main.py is very program focused. Mixing them gives you the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> #### 6.1.2. The Module Search Path
>
> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
> - **`PYTHONPATH`** (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable PATH).
> - The installation-dependent default.

This is how you import your modules:

```
from boo.boo1.b import BModule
```

So, the base (root) folder of the imports is the one that contains `boo`. Based on your `sys.path`:

```
['/Users/okoo/Code/projectRoot/boo/boo2', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/okoo/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

It doesn't have `'/Users/okoo/Code/projectRoot'`. Add it to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable as documented:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Users/okoo/Code/projectRoot
```

Or to not override an existing value:

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/Users/okoo/Code/projectRoot
```

Or if you want to do this programmatically, use `sys.path.append()`.

Comment: shouldn't __init__.py include the project root?

Comment: It shouldn't be required.